# d3 zooming/panning behavior changes at millisecond intervals

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working in a problem domain where I need to display data at millisecond time intervals. I have found that when you zoom in far enough on a graph, the behavior of the zoom/pan functions suddenly change! If you are using a time scale, this happens exactly when your axis starts displaying milliseconds.

Specifically, the behavior change is how d3 zooms around the mouse cursor. For intervals measured in seconds or above, the gridlines zoom with respect to the cursor position. i.e Mousing over 6PM and scrolling will cause 6PM to take up more space. But once you get to milliseconds, the grid seems to be zoomed from the far left, regardless of your cursor position. The panning also stops moving the axis around at all.

I am not very experienced in d3, but to me, this looks like a bug. I see nothing in the zoom documentation about this. Is there a reason why it behaves this way, and if so, can it be overridden somehow?

In the links below, as soon as you zoom far enough that the x-axis labels change from :YY to .YYY (ie. :50 to .653) you should see the problem.

This shows the "broken"  behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/JonathanPullano/LuYDY/3/

This shows the "correct" behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/JonathanPullano/LuYDY/2/

EDIT: I have discovered that the problem is not in the zoom behavior, but rather the time.scale() itself. I made another fiddle which uses setTimeout to automatically rescale the axis without using zoom. The problem still persists. Try it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/JonathanPullano/LuYDY/4/

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([-5000, 5000])
    .range([0, width]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var gXAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSize(-height);

        gXAxis.call(xAxis);
    });
}

update();
function update() {
  var start = new Date(x.domain()[0].getTime() + 10);
  var end = new Date(x.domain()[1].getTime() - 10);
  if(start.getTime() < end.getTime()) {
    x.domain([start,end]);
    setTimeout(update,10);
  }
  svg.call(chart);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom and pan is behaving as expected, but the tick marks/ grid lines are being drawn at different values each time, which makes it look erratic at first and at extreme zooms makes it look like the grids aren't moving.

I've modified your fiddle to use a more complete tick format function, and also to draw a circle in the same point (on the scales) each time:

http://jsfiddle.net/LuYDY/5/

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M.%L") );
```

As you can see, the values zoom and pan as expected, but the tick values always get spaced at the same points on the window, rather than at round numbers of milliseconds.

The bug is simply that the time scale's definition of "nice" round datetime value falls apart at this scale.  Explicitly telling the scale to be `.nice()` doesn't work, either.

The time scale methods try to find a suitable time unit for choosing ticks, and that doesn't work when the entire domain is less than 1 second.  What would be ideal is if it switched to a linear scale definition of "nice" (i.e., round to multiples of powers of 10).

I.e. if you do:

```
x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([10, 477])
    .nice();
```

And then query the x domain and convert the values back to integers, you still get exactly [10,477].  If you did that with a linear scale, the domain would be rounded off to [0,500].  Similarly, tick values for that time scale are placed at exact fractions of the domain, but are placed at round numbers for the linear scale.

You could make this an issue request on github.  In the meantime, if your data domain is in the millisecond range, maybe just use a linear scale.

Comment: I actually made a github issue about this a few hours ago and mbostock has already committed a fix for version 3.4.x

Comment: Awesome.  Glad it was fairly straightforward solution.